# Count incoming unbouned messages from pubsub using apache beam java

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

My requirment is to count incoming records from pubsub for every 5min period in apache beam pipeline using java sdk

```
class Display extends DoFn<Long,String>
{
@ProcessElement
public void process(ProcessContext c)
{
System.out.println(c.element());
}
}
public class CustomMetrics
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
PipelineOptions options = PipelineFactory.create();
Pipleine pipeline= Pipeline.create(options);

pipeline.apply(PubsubIO.readStrings().fromSubscription("PubSub Subscription"))
.apply(Window.<String>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(5))).triggering(DefaultTrigger.of()))
.apply(Combine.globally(Count.<String>combineFn()).withoutDefaults())
.apply(ParDo.of(new Display()));

pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
}
}
```

Able to count the incoming records but the number is not displayed immediatley its populated randomly after some time.

Is there any other way to count the incoming unbouneded records using Apache Beam pipleine.

Comment: It worked in dataflow displaying number of records read from pubsub for every 5 min period. Thanks @Jan Lukavsky

Answer (score 0):

Apache Beam uses the concept of *[event time](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#event-time-triggers)* to ensure consistent computation results on unordered streams. Because every distributed data stream is necessarily unordered there needs to be a way synchronize different workers processing the data. Apache Beam uses for this purpose a *[watermark](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#watermarks-and-late-data)*, which is a periodically generated marker that flows from sources and propagates though all PTransforms in the Pipeline. The lag you notice is therefore related exactly to the delay between data is processed and when watermark which marks end-of-window arrives.

Watermarks are most often generated on sources (PubsubIO.Read in your case) by some heuristic. These heuristics tend to produce higher latency for low-volume streams, so you might try to experiment with the volume of data you write to you Pubsub topic.

Last but not least the lag depends on a runner you choose to run your Pipeline. In the example above I suppose you use DirectRunner, which is mostly used for testing and is not optimized for performance. You can try different runners and see how your outputs change.